Network limitation on ec2 instance
I am running a workload on the c6i.12xlarge instance. Judging by https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ it should have a 18.75 GBPS network bandwidth and 15 GBPS ebs bandwidth.
What I am observing though, is that after initial burst, there is a flattening curve on the bandwidth, checking with speedtest shows that once the plateu is reached, the speed is indeed limited

Am I missing something obvious?

Nvm, turns out I was restricted by a custom nat gw t4g instance
